# Error while passing variables in sed

Tags: unix, sed

My script:

```
while read start_val
do
end_value = "$start_val+10" | bc

sed -n '"$start_value","$end_value"d'  <file>
done < in_file
```

Actually I want to print the lines of a file using the data taken from input file by doing some calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It is because variables are not expanded inside of single quotes ('). Try for instance

```
echo '$HOME'
```

vs

```
echo "$HOME"
```

The same goes for your example with the single quotes after sed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like:

```
sed -n "$start_value,$end_value"'d' $file
```

btw no need to use bc there:

```
while read start_val
do
    end_value=$((start_val+10))
    sed "$start_value,$end_value"'d' $file
    # not sure what above sed is doing since you're not storing output anywhere!
done < in_file
```

Comment: $ while read val
> do
> s_val = "$val+3"|bc
> sed -n "$val,$s_val"'d' line_no.txt
> done < abc.txt
sh[3]: s_val:  not found.
sed: 3,d is not a recognized function.

Comment: pls don't post script in comments, edit your question and post it there.

Answer (score 1):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for any other text manipulation, just use awk:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { in_file[FNR] = $0; next }
{ for (i=$0; i<=$0+10; i++) print in_file[i] }
' in_file file
```

Not that your original script was using -n to tell sed not to print any lines and then d to tell sed to delete some lines so it wouldn't produce any output so I'm not sure what you really wanted to do, the awk script is a guess.

Comment: I m new to scripting. Thanks for guiding me the exact usage of -n for sed command. My task is to print the lines of a file by taking the input from the another file by add/subtract to the actual number.

Comment: thats what my script does. did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n $start_value','$end_value'p' file
```

this will print all lines from $start_value to $end_value.

Comment: sed -n $start_value','$end_value'p' file